# Objective-c constant static NSArray

Tags: objective-c, constants, compile-time-constant

I am a Java programmer, learning Objective-C and I have a problem with implementation of variables, similar to static final class variables in Java. In class PolygonShape, I would like to have NSDictionary with polygon types, which can be accessed from within and outside of the class. I already tried the following:

PolygonShape.h:

```
...
extern NSDictionary *polygonTypes;

@interface PolygonShape
...
```

PolygonShape.m:

```
...    
NSDictionary *polygonTypes = nil;

@implementation PolygonShape

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if(!polygonTypes) {
            polygonTypes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"triangle", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3], @"quadrilateral", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 4],
                            @"pentagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 5], @"hexagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 6],
                            @"heptagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 7], @"octagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8],  
                            @"enneagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 9], @"decagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10],
                            @"hendecagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 11], @"dodecagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12], nil];
        }
    }
...
```

But this is not good enough, because if I want to access polygon types from elsewhere (e.g. main.m) without initializing instance of PolygonShape, variable polygonTypes is nil. So I used static function which works fine:

PolygonShape.m:

```
static NSDictionary *polygonTypes = nil;

@implementation PolygonShape

...

+ (NSDictionary *) polygonTypesDicionary {
    if(!polygonTypes) {
        polygonTypes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"triangle", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3], @"quadrilateral", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 4],
                        @"pentagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 5], @"hexagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 6],
                        @"heptagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 7], @"octagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8],  
                        @"enneagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 9], @"decagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10],
                        @"hendecagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 11], @"dodecagon", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12], nil];
    }
    return polygonTypes;
}
```

Now this is ok, but I wonder, what is the best way to do this and is it possible to use extern for NSDictionary without having to initialize it in a class method? (and I know about singelton classes but I would really like to have constant array of polygon types inside PolygonShape class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am a Java programmer, […]

There's your problem right there.

Objective-C is a quite different language from Java in a lot of ways, and a lot of idioms may be quite foreign to you.

As an example; why do you want, or need, to know what kind of polygon shapes the Polygon class can handle?

If you are trying to create a polygon with a certain number of corners, but can't, then yes, you need to know.

Apart from that? Not very useful info, at least as far as I can see.

In fact, why would a polygon shape even need to know what *other* shapes exist?

Shed for a moment the very **idea** of `static`, and reconsider your problem. Enlightenment is sure to follow.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I know Objective-C is quite different, but I would like to achieve something similar to java static final variables in general. PolygonShape is maybe a bad example though...

Comment: @PavleGartner: I got that, my point was that static final variables aren't really something you use in Objective-C, to any great degree. It's a pattern of a different programming language, and of a different framework. First, think about what you want to achieve, then how to achieve it. (static variables, btw, are a "how")

Comment: I have always thought that Objective-C could perhaps add an away literal like we have string litterals for example just like we declare string literals like @"My String", perhaps we could have array littorals like @{@"One",@"Two"} of cause all we could stick in them is string literals, unless that added a similar syntax for other kinds like @5 for a NSNumber literal.